# Enable/disable lock screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

it´s posible to enable and disable lock screen?

My aplication connect with wcf in order to read data from dababase. This data could be very large.Application works fine on emulator and on device when I execute it from Visual Studio. But I execute it without VS, if screen is locked, when unlock it application crash, are closed. Í have a try cath, but catch part is not executed, directaly close application.

it´s posible to disable lock screen when are reciving data and anable again on finished.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the application to run under lockscreen by disabling the idle detection

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

and enabling it again when no longer needed.

Comment: sorry In app.xaml I have PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled and lock screen raised

Comment: put it in tej App.xaml.cs constructor

Answer (score 1):

You could either disable the lockscreen from triggering

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled; // or .Enabled
```

or, you could make the app run under the lockscreen

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled; // or .Enabled
```

one thing to note though: the phone throws an exception if the UserIdleDetectionMode is changed twice in the application. It still changes the UserIdleDetectionMode though, so a try and catch block should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a mistake. I was writing under  if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)

Thanks